# Powershell check if drive letter exists and if so remove

Tags: powershell

I have a script that checks whether there are drives with certain letters.
If that letter exists, it will removes these letter.
Then the script goes looking for drives according to their 'labels' in changes their letters according to what is specified in the script.

**I'm looking to perfect the script so that in the first part it will look for any drives with the letters E or D, and if so, remove them.
If it is not found, then just go to the second part of changing according to the label of the disk.**

```
Get-Volume -DriveLetter E | Get-Partition | Remove-PartitionAccessPath -AccessPath E:\
Get-Volume -DriveLetter D | Get-Partition | Remove-PartitionAccessPath -AccessPath D:\

$DataPartition = Get-WMIObject Win32_Volume | where{ $_.Label -eq 'Data'}
$FileServerPartition = Get-WMIObject Win32_Volume | where{ $_.Label -eq 'FileServer'}

$DataPartition.DriveLetter = $null
$DataPartition.Put()
$FileServerPartition.DriveLetter = $null
$FileServerPartition.Put()


Try
{
    Set-WmiInstance -input $DataPartition -Arguments @{DriveLetter="D:"} | Out-File -FilePath  C:\Windows\Temp\FixPartitionsLog.txt -Append
    Set-WmiInstance -input $FileServerPartition -Arguments @{DriveLetter="E:"} | Out-File -FilePath  C:\Windows\Temp\FixPartitionsLog.txt -Append
}
Catch
{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message | Out-File -FilePath C:\Windows\Temp\FixPartitionsLog.txt
}
sleep 5
Restart-Service server -Force
```

Comment: `Remove-PSDrive -Name E, D -ErrorAction Ignore`. This will ignore _all_ errors, however, so a problem other than such drives not having been defined wouldn't surface until later.

Comment: why don't you get the drives available first with a command like `Get-WmiObject -query "SELECT * from win32_logicaldisk where DriveType = '3'"` but maybe this blog post will help you https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/09/10/inventory-drive-types-by-using-powershell/

Comment: Depends on what type of drive you want to remove and add later. DriveType 2 = Removable Disk, 3 = Fixed Local Disk, 4 = Network Drive

Answer (score 3):

This was the solution I used in the end:

```
$driveLetters= (Get-Volume).DriveLetter
if ($driveLetters -contains "d" -or $driveLetters -contains "e")
{
switch ($driveLetters)
{
    "d" {Get-Volume -DriveLetter D | Get-Partition | Remove-PartitionAccessPath -AccessPath D:\}
    "e" {Get-Volume -DriveLetter E | Get-Partition | Remove-PartitionAccessPath -AccessPath E:\}
}
}

$DataPartition = Get-WMIObject Win32_Volume | where{ $_.Label -eq 'Data'}
$FileServerPartition = Get-WMIObject Win32_Volume | where{ $_.Label -eq 'FileServer'}

$DataPartition.DriveLetter = $null
$DataPartition.Put()
$FileServerPartition.DriveLetter = $null
$FileServerPartition.Put()



Try
{
    Set-WmiInstance -input $DataPartition -Arguments @{DriveLetter="D:"} | Out-File -FilePath  C:\Windows\Temp\FixPartitionsLog.txt -Append
    Set-WmiInstance -input $FileServerPartition -Arguments @{DriveLetter="E:"} | Out-File -FilePath  C:\Windows\Temp\FixPartitionsLog.txt -Append

}
Catch
{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message | Out-File -FilePath C:\Windows\Temp\FixPartitionsLog.txt
}
sleep 5
Restart-Service server -Force
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I included few notes to this answer in mine.

Answer (score 0):

I already had a function doing what you want.
I included it as it was, but you actually only need 5 lines from it.
And there is a slight difference from what you asked. 
Only letters for found Labels are removed.
e.g. If 'Data' label is not found, but 'D:\' exists, the letter 'D' will not be removed.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param()
function Set-Partition_NewDriveLetter_Force {
    param(
      [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)][Alias('InputObject')]
      $DiskPartition,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
      [System.Char]$NewDriveLetter
    )
      # if (Test-Path -LiteralPath "${NewDriveLetter}:\") { # will error if letter does not exist
      # if (Get-Volume -DriveLetter $NewDriveLetter) {      # will error if letter does not exist
      if (Get-Volume -FilePath "${NewDriveLetter}:\") {
          if ($DiskPartition.DriveLetter -ne $NewDriveLetter) {
              Write-Verbose "Letter $NewDriveLetter is already taken by other volume, removing and adding to detected volume..."
              Remove-PartitionAccessPath -DriveLetter $NewDriveLetter -AccessPath "${NewDriveLetter}:\"
              Set-Partition -InputObject $DiskPartition -NewDriveLetter $NewDriveLetter
          } else { Write-Verbose "Letter $NewDriveLetter is already assigned to this volume." }
      } else {
          Write-Verbose "Letter $NewDriveLetter is being assigned to detected volume."
          Set-Partition -InputObject $DiskPartition -NewDriveLetter $NewDriveLetter
      }
  }


foreach ($p in Get-Volume | Where-Object { $_.FileSystemLabel -in 'Recovery', 'SYSTEM' }) {
    Write-Host "Found drive with Label: $($p.FileSystemLabel)"
    switch ($p.FileSystemLabel) {
        'Recovery' { $p | Get-Partition | Set-Partition_NewDriveLetter_Force -NewDriveLetter 'R' }
        'SYSTEM' { $p | Get-Partition | Set-Partition_NewDriveLetter_Force -NewDriveLetter 'S' }
    }
}
```

## Use:

If this was saved to a ps1 file and called with `-Verbose` argument, it will show more output.

## Explanation:

I named the function and included parameters similar to a Cmdlet doing similar function.

First two lines enables 'advanced function' for the script block. It's needed only for `-Verbose` to work.

As can be seen in comments, `Get-Volume -FilePath 'X:\'` is the only way I found to not error if volume letter is not present. `(Get-Volume).DriveLetter` will also error if there are none letters, but which is not much likely.

I limit number of disk queries, although that might not actually gain much speed.

## Note to your answer:

You don't need `if ($driveLetters -contains "d" -or $driveLetters -contains "e")`
when it's followed by `switch` which is also a conditional statement in this case doing the same job.

You don't need both Get-Volume and Get-Partition, as Get-Partition also has -DriveLetter argument:
`"d" { Get-Partition -DriveLetter D | Remove-PartitionAccessPath -AccessPath D:\ }`

You don't need WMI for reading label, Get-Volume has Label property.
Sometimes it might be faster to use .NET, or WMI directly, in opposed to calling PS Cmdlets,
but there are reasons to not mix those until there is no other way.